# Viewing the top items in a LongListSelector on WP8 when SIP is open

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have an app that uses a LongListSelector to display a list of items, at the bottom of the page I have a TextBox. When the TextBox is tapped, the SIP displays itself. At this point, I'm unable to then scroll to the top of the LLS.

Sample code:

XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="TheList">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                list.Add("This is string number " + i);
            }

            TheList.ItemsSource = list;
        };
    }
```

This is as much as I can see, I can pull down to string number 5, but can't see any higher:
[image: LongListSelector Problem]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You might find the following useful : http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScrollViewer` doesn't take into account the SIP so its scrolling experience is the same as when the SIP is not visible (which is why the top can't be reached). One workaround would be to add a margin to the top of the `LongListSelector`, (or the bottom if your textbox is at the top), when the SIP is displayed.

As there's no event for the SIP, you can handle the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events of the TextBox. (The `180` value was obtained via trial and error)

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TheList.Margin = new Thickness(0,180,0,0);
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TheList.Margin = new Thickness();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I did try that with a 160 margin, didn't make a noticable difference, just tried it with a top margin of 350 and now it makes a difference. Thanks for prompting me to keep trying with that :)